# HTMLTableCellElement> has no method 'text in jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to fetch last 'tr' of the   table and find out the 3rd cell value of that last tr selected. 
I am using below statement

```
alert($("#requirements_table tr:last").find("td")[1].text());
```

but I get the error :

HTMLTableCellElement> has no method 'text

Table structure

```
<table id="requirements_table">
    <% @requirements.each do |requirement| %>
      <tr>

        <td><div contenteditable><%= requirement.id %></div></td>

        <td><%= requirement.requirement_info %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', requirement %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_requirement_path(requirement),:class=> "edit_req" %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', requirement, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
```

Comment: the error you are getting it says it all. HTML Table Cell Nodes do not contain a `text` method. jQuery objects however do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

`$("#requirements_table tr:last").find("td")[1].text()`

to

`$("#requirements_table tr:last").find("td").eq(1).text()`

As the error indicates `.find("td")[1]` - return DOM element which doesn't have function `.text()`

Instead you need to use `.eq` function like `.find("td").eq(1).text()` which return the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Bracket notation on a jQuery object returns you the underlying HTML element. To access a jQuery object at a given index you'll want to use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$("#requirements_table tr:last").find("td").eq(1).text()
```